# Error al enviar XML/string a web services C#

Tags: c#, xml, webservice

Tengo el SoapUI donde estoy realizando una prueba de web services en cual añado 3 datos al request y este me da una respuesta, hasta aqui todo bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sucede que quiero consumir ese webservice usando C#, el codigo que tengo hasta ahora es:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string uno = "2018-12-05T17:00:00";
            string dos = "3101009059";
            string tres = "2018-11-28T00:00:00";

            string xmlData = @"<con:contractNoticeReqBean>
                                 <java:End_ymd>"+uno+ @"</java:End_ymd>
                                 <java:Inst_reg_no>"+dos+@"</java:Inst_reg_no>
                                 <java:Start_ymd>"+ tres + @"</java:Start_ymd>
                              </con:contractNoticeReqBean>";

            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);

            ServiceReference1.ContractInfoWServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ContractInfoWServiceClient();
            var data = client.getRequestContractNotice(xmlDoc);


        }
```

Pero cuando corro el codigo me lanza un error en la linea `xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlData);` el error es:

> System.Xml.XmlException: ''con' es un prefijo no declarado. línea 1,
>   posición 2.'

Si trato de enviar el string `xmlData` el error que me señala antes de poder correr el codigo en la linea `var data = client.getRequestContractNotice(xmlDoc);`   es:

> Argumento 1: no se puede convertir de 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' a
>   'xml.ServiceReference1.ContractNoticeReqBean'

Como puedo solucionar esto con el fin de poder enviar esos 3 datos de forma correcta.

**EDITADO**

Lo edite de esta forma para enviar los datos:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            DateTime final = DateTime.Parse("2018-12-05T17:00:00");
            string ints = "3101009059";
            DateTime inicio = DateTime.Parse("2018-11-28T00:00:00");

            ServiceReference1.ContractNoticeReqBean reqBean=new ServiceReference1.ContractNoticeReqBean();
            reqBean.End_ymd = final;
            reqBean.Inst_reg_no = ints;
            reqBean.Start_ymd = inicio;

            ServiceReference1.ContractInfoWServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ContractInfoWServiceClient();
            var data = client.getRequestContractNotice(reqBean);
            listBox1.Items.Add(data);


        }
```

Quiero recibir estos datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero mi salida es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cual es mi fallo ahora?

Comment: Pero si el metodo `getRequestContractNotice` no espera un `XmlDocument`, debes de crear una clase del tipo `ContractNoticeReqBean` pasarle los valores a cada propiedad y luego lo pasas como parametro al metodo `getRequestContractNotice`

Comment: Estas confundiendo la forma en que SoapUI hace la consulta con el proxy `ServiceReference1` que ya creaste al mapiar el servicio desde visual studio (me supongo que estas usano vs).

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa si estoy usando visual, ya mas o menos le voy agarrando la idea pero cuando envio los datos, me devuelve `xml.ServiceReference1.ReqConNumBean` y no el XML, edito la pregunta para mostrar el avance

Comment: Coloca el cursor en el metodo `getRequestContractNotice` y dale f12, o click derecho y luego "go to reference" o ir a referencia. y fijate que te retorna el metodo, si lo puedes colocar en la pregunta mejor.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias, ya pude, lo que tenia que hacer era recuperar los datos en forma de `xml.ServiceReference1.ReqConNumBean`y despues iterarlo en un foreach

Comment: Exacto, por eso te mande a que revisas la referencia del metodo.